# ERROR in ./node_modules/@chakra-ui/hooks/dist/chakra-ui-hooks.esm.js 238:11-22

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I installed chakra-ui via,

npm i @chakra-ui/react @emotion/react@^11 @emotion/styled@^11 framer-motion@^6

while using ChakraProvider component I'm getting following error.

[image: The Error]

[image: My package.json file]

Comment: What is the react version?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is I'm using react17 version, after upgraded to 18 problem solved.

```
"@chakra-ui/react": "^2.0.0",
.
.
.
"react": "^18.1.0",
"react-dom": "^18.1.0",
```

As official docs of chakra UI suggests: "Version 2 of Chakra UI is only compatible with React 18. If you are still needing to use React 17 or later, please use version 1 of Chakra UI."

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem and all you have to do is   `npm install react@latest react-dom@latest` this installs the latest version of react